# Append Flink job name to every log statement

Tags: java, append, apache-flink, log4j2

In every specific Flink app I can use whatever logger (logback, log4j2, etc.) with appropriate configuration.

But in standalone mode, the actual configuration used is not the one in my `jar` file because Flink has it own configuration files (log4j2 by default), which take precedence over my own.

The goal is to pass job name (not jobId) to my logs like this:

`10/06/2023 21:05:22.527[my-flink-application-0.1.3]  INFO [org.example.service.MainSourceFunction] : Hello world`

Is there any best way to do this?